# Static site with Redux, React Router & Webpack

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, react-router, redux

I can't seem to get static-site-generator-webpack-plugin to work with React & React Router. Also can't seem to find any example.

Help please?

Comment: You need to be more specific about the problems you're having if you want help. Please explain where you are in the process and post any error message you're getting.

Comment: I just published [ReactRouterPathExtractorWebpackPlugin](https://github.com/mbaasy/react-router-path-extractor-webpack-plugin) for use with React Router, and StaticSiteGeneratorWebpackPlugin